# My website started to load slow after I added mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am sorry if there is lack of information I'm not that really good of explaining and English is not my native language.

After I designed the website with `html/css` etc...I started to add `mysqli`, to display the user information, tables.

Comment: You need to remove your link. Your site is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: You seem to connect a new instance of MySQLi each time your use any of your functions - that's highly ineffective.

Comment: @dutchasperity other answers told you what is wrong with your code. I only want to recommend you using some ORM tool like Propel or Doctrine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just glimmsed at your code: In every function, you are calling `db_login()`, which opens every time a new database connection. Try to reuse the same database connection, would speed up a lot.

For example you can make a global variable, where you open the connection once and then import the variable via the [global keyword](http://php.net/language.variables.scope), or you could pass the functions this variable as parameter. This best option though, would be designing the whole thing into a class, where the (open) connection is a shared variable of the instance of this class.